# The geometric mean of primes less than or equal to $x$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

I want to show that the limit of the geometric mean of primes less than or equal to $x$ is $e$ as $x \to \infty$. Is this correct?

Using the product law of logarithms we have
$$\ln \prod\limits_{p \leqslant x} p  = \sum\limits_{p \leqslant x} {\ln (p)}$$
but
$$\sum\limits_{p \leqslant x} {\ln (p)}  = \vartheta (x) \sim x$$
hence
$$\prod\limits_{p \leqslant x} p  \sim {e^x}$$
and the geometric mean is
$${\left( {\prod\limits_{p \leqslant x} p } \right)^{1/x}} \sim e.$$

Edit: I realized that this product does not represent the geometric mean. What does it represent?

Comment: You are not calculating the geometric mean.  The geometric mean would involve taking the $1/\pi(x)$ power, not the $1/x$ power.  That is, the number of primes would need to be involved.  The geometric mean of these primes is certainly an increasing function of $x$.

Comment: @MatthewConroy I am not sure what this is called, but it looks similar to the geometric mean.

Comment: Which step(s) in your argument are you unsure of?

Comment: Are my arguments valid and what does ${\left( {\prod\nolimits_{p \leqslant x} p } \right)^{1/x}}$ represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geometric mean of the collection of primes numbers less than $x$ can be written:

$$G(x)=\left( \prod_{p \le x} p\right)^{\frac{1}{\pi(x)}}$$
$$\log(G(x))=\frac{1}{\pi(x)}\sum_{p \le x}\log(p)=\frac{\vartheta(x)}{\pi(x)}$$

For large $x$, we can use the PNT and an asymptotic for the first Chebyshev function given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevFunctions.html):

$$\log(G(x)) \sim \frac{\log(x)}{x} \cdot x= \log(x)$$

Thus, $G(x) \sim x$. Here's a plot:

[image: Plot of geometric mean of primes less than $x$ for $0 \le x \le 10,000$.]

A best fit line reveals $G(x) \approx .31473x$. So I think the more interesting question to ask is what is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{G(x)}{x}$? Can it be expressed in terms of known constants?

Comment: This is fascinating because the arithmetic mean of all primes is asymptotically $x/2$, so the geometric mean is asymptotically $e$ to the power of the arithmetic mean. Truth amazing. Thanks.

Comment: What does ${\left( {\prod\nolimits_{p \leqslant x} p } \right)^{1/x}}$ represent?

Comment: "Amazing"...and truly wrong.  Because $e^{x/2}$ exceeds $x$ for all positive $x$, this answer claims that an *average* of values all of which are less than $x$ actually *exceeds* $x$! (The source of the error appears to be failure to divide $s(n)$ by $n$ in the linked answer.)

Comment: I used the wrong asymptotic. I'm summing the $\log$ of primes up to $x$, not the sum of primes up to $x$. If you can provide an appropriate asymptotic for the sum of the log of primes then this should be solvable.

Comment: Fixed. Better constants for the asymptotic estimates will probably yield more accurate values for $G(x)$.

Comment: $\log G(x)\sim\log x$ does *not* imply $G(x)\sim x$ but only $G(x)=x^{1+o(1)}.$

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised the answer to this query is no where on the web?

Taking logs, you want to take $S(N)=\sum_{p\le N}\log p$ [the product] and then quotient this by $T(N)=\sum_{p\le N} 1$ [the number of primes] before reexponentiating for the final result. By partial summation, we have

$$S(N)=T(N)\log N-\int_2^N T(u){du\over u}$$

and the integral is $N/\log(N)$ to first order, for $T(u)\sim u/\log(u)$ by PNT. So ${S(N)\over T(N)}$ is $(\log N)-1$, and exponentiating gets you $N/e$ as the answer.