# Is there a proof of an infinite number of prime numbers using the irrationality of $e$?

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, alternative-proof, continued-fractions

That the set of prime integers is infinite can be proved using the irrationality of $\pi$; see this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_theorem#Proof_using_the_irrationality_of_%CF%80). It analyzes the representation

$\tag 1 {\displaystyle {\frac {\pi }{4}}={\frac {3}{4}}\times {\frac {5}{4}}\times {\frac {7}{8}}\times {\frac {11}{12}}\times {\frac {13}{12}}\times {\frac {17}{16}}\times {\frac {19}{20}}\times {\frac {23}{24}}\times {\frac {29}{28}}\times {\frac {31}{32}}\times \cdots }$

It 'seems only fair' that the same thing can be done using $e$:

> Question 1: Has a proof that there are an infinite number of primes been
>   constructed that uses the irrationality of $e$?

If the existence of such a proof is not available, then

> Question 1-1: Is a proof available using any properties of $e$?

If again, no answers, then

> Question 2: Can someone show that the set of prime integers is
>   infinite using properties of Euler's constant?

**My work**

I found [this representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Representations) of $e$,

$\tag 2 {\displaystyle e=1+{\cfrac {2}{1+{\cfrac {1}{6+{\cfrac {1}{10+{\cfrac {1}{14+{\cfrac {1}{18+{\cfrac {1}{22+{\cfrac {1}{26+\ddots \,}}}}}}}}}}}}}}.}$

Note that with $\text{(1)}$ there is a 'corresponding' sequence

$\tag 3 4,8,12,16,\dots$

and that with $\text{(2)}$ we can see

$\tag 4 6, 10,14,18,\dots$

I just find this interesting; perhaps it supplies a 'connection'.

We know that eventually every prime number will divide a term in the $\text{(4)}$ sequence.

If the only primes are contained in the finite set $\mathcal P = \{2,3,5, \dots, p\}$, then let $\beta = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times \dots \times p$.

**If we analyze $\text{(2)}$ using base $\beta$, the expansion of $e$ would eventually be repetitive or simply terminate.**

(the statement in bold is an unproven bold statement)

Comment: It's hard to see why one would want to prove it that way, as the usual $1+\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$ argument does it easily.

Comment: Or, better still, try and figure it out from what I have just said.

Comment: @RichardMartin Ok - Euclid's proof. Just interested in seeing a 'later stage' proof.

Comment: @RichardMartin Someone putting up the wiki article thought it was interesting enough to put down the $\pi$ proof...

Comment: @RichardMartin Also, I think that the primes are really 'joined to the hip' with $e$ (and not $\pi$), but I can't come up with anything coherent.

Comment: @RichardMartin More proofs = more fun. But seriously, new proofs to existing theorems are interesting because of any novel ideas they might contain, not because they achieve the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

We can give a proof based on the transcendentality of $e$:

Since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} p_i\right)^{1/p_n}=e,$$

if the set of prime numbers was finite then $e$ would be algebraic.

Comment: Can't find a link to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} p_i\right)^{1/p_n}=e,$ ...(guessing if follows from the prime number theorem)

Comment: Did you check all the proof to make sure there is no circular reasoning here?

Comment: @CopyPasteIt Here you have some info: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231578/the-geometric-mean-of-primes-less-than-or-equal-to-x ... The fact is strongly related to the PNT; in fact it comes from the asymptotics of Chebyshev function $\theta$. You could say that it is a "cooked" relation with $e$, since we could do just with a lower bound on $\theta$, which is implicit. Yet again, we can do with way less in order to prove the infinitude of primes :P Not circular, but we would arrive first to the conclusion due to the asymptotics...